Sidebar is not working properly in laravel
Sidebar file
@php
    $activeRoutes = [
        'dashboard' => request()->routeIs('dashboard'),
    ];
@endphp

<div class="sidebar-menu-list">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="{{ $activeRoutes['dashboard'] ? 'active' : '' }}" href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">
                <img class="image-default" src="{{ asset('/assets_admin/images/menu-icon/dashboard.svg') }}" alt="Icon">
                <img class="image-hover" src="{{ asset('/assets_admin/images/menu-icon/dashboard-hover.svg') }}" alt="Icon"> 
                Dashboard
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

Dashboard file
<table id="withdraw-request" data-searching="false" data-ordering="false">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Edit</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($aas as $key => $a)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="listing-custom-drp position-relative">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/edit-2.png') }}" alt="Edit">
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                            <li><a href="{{ route('test', ['id' => $par->id]) }}#pills-1">Hotel Content Management</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('test1', ['id' => $par->id]) }}#pills-2">Services</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>

I am adding class in sidebar file dynamically which is heighlight my sidebar menu it is working properly but when i click on any button from dashboard route is not change then also my sidebar menu is not highlighting how can i solve this?
